# how to add check mark in context menu

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

i build a context menu and i want when user click on contextmenuitem then check mark tick is visible with contextmenuitem and when again user click on the same contextmenu item then check mark tick is visible off

Answer (score 0):

if you're publishing AIR you can set the *checked* property of the contextMenuItem ([NativeMenuItem](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/NativeMenuItem.html)) object.

```
myNativeMenuItem.checked = true;
```

Comment: ContextMenuItem does not have property of checked

Comment: since ContextMenuItem is a subclass of NativeMenuItem (which holds the "checked" property), it too has that property thru inheritance.  ContextMenuItem -> NativeMenuItem -> EventDispatcher -> Object.  however, as i mentioned, NativeMenuItem is AIR only.